# LINQ to SQL dynamic order by with IN operator?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by

I have the following LINQ query:

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext()) {
    int[] onlineUsers = GetOnline();
    var users = (from u in db.Users orderby 
        (onlineUsers.Contains(u.u_username) && 
        u.u_hasvisible_photo) descending,
        u.u_lastlogin descending select 
        u.u_username).Skip(startRowIndex).
        Take(maximumRows).ToList();
}
```

This works fine and generates a SQL query using IN operator.

The problem is that every int from the int[] is passed via a different parameter and I know SQL has a limit of 2100 parameters per query.

I think it would be better to use LINQ Dynamic library OrderBy to do the sorting.

Instead of "onlineUsers.Contains(u.u_username) && u.u_hasvisible_photo) descending" use .OrderBy(orderquery).

I have searched online for guide or example to do this and can't find any help.Could the community assist me with code or links that may assist me in implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you could create a scalar function which takes a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) and then pass the array in as that.  It might require special coaxing from the LINQ provider though (you didn't specify which one you were using (Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-SQL, and I'm assuming SQL Server, even though you just say "sql"), so I'm not sure how composable the query will be.

What you might want to do is create a [table valued user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) which takes the table-valued parameter (and any other parameters you might have) and expose that through LINQ (you should be able to create something composable from the table-valued function) and then proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for **Linq to SQL** which allows you to order dynamically. The example is using the **Northwind** database, and you can simply try it out with **[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)**:

```
void Main()
{

    // Demonstrates dynamic ordering

    var SortExpression = "Total"; // choose ProductName or Total
    var sortAscending = true; // choose true for ascending, false for descending

    // the query to sort
    var data = (from pd in Products
                        join od in OrderDetails on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID into DetailsByProduct
                        select new { ProductName = pd.ProductName, Total = DetailsByProduct.Count()}).ToList();

    // the data source you can use for data binding                     
    var ds= (sortAscending) 
        ? data.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(SortExpression).GetValue(x, null))
        : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(SortExpression).GetValue(x, null));

    ds.Dump();
}
```

Try to replace `"Total"` by `"ProductName"` (variable `SortExpression`), or to sort descending by using `false` (variable `sortAscending`).